# Delphi quickbooks

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, quickbooks

Am trying to connect to a quickbooks company file through the qbfc library using delphi 7.

Imported the type Library which has created a QBFC12Lib_TLB file

Included the file to my form's uses list

Code for connecting to the library

```
var
  TempSession : QBSessionManager;
  TempRequest : IMsgSetRequest;
  TempCustomer : ICustomerAdd;
  TempResponse : IMsgSetResponse;
  AppID, AppName : WideString;
begin
  AppID := '123';
  AppName := 'Hello';
  TempSession.OpenConnection2(AppID, AppName, ctLocalQBDLaunchUI);
  TempSession.BeginSession('', omDontCare);
```

But an access violation error occurs on "TempSession.OpenConnection2 ...."

Has anyone tried this or could anyone have some samples on how to do this?

Comment: Like any other Delphi class or interface, you need to actually create it before you can use it. Look at the type library (TLB file), at the classes Delphi creates for you. You'll see one that is something like `TQBSessionManager` which has a `Create` constructor. Use that, like `TempSession := TQBSessionManager.Create;` (you'll need to look at that constructor to see exactly how to call it, as I don't have QB installed - if I did, I'd post an answer instead). After calling the constructor, you should then be able to use `TempSession.OpenConnection2` and the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `Ken White` suggests (and as shown in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173859/how-to-get-list-of-customers-jobs-and-employeers-using-quickbooks-qbfc-8-0-sd)), you need to instantiate the `QBSessionManager` object before you call `OpenConnection2`

```
QBSessionManager TempSession = new QBSessionManager();
```

or possibly (although I could not find any examples that used this notation)

```
TempSession := QBSessionManager.Create();
```

Comment: Thanks a million @Sam It seems I was using QBSessionManager instead of TQBSessionManager